# Can't get PHP to load mongo.so extension

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, xampp

I've tried building the library with PECL, I've tried downloading it from github.  I've tried MAMP, I've tried XAMPP.  I always get the same error:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so: unknown required load command 0x80000022 in Unknown on line 0

(Paths differ depending on XAMPP or MAMP)

I'm running OS 10.5.8.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just going off of the error message there, I can tell you this is an architecture-related issue (for example, see [this](http://asqueella.blogspot.com/2010/12/dyld-unknown-required-load-command.html)). XAMPP is still 32-bit only according to [this question on their FAQ](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-linux.html#oci8), and PECL will try to build extensions as 64-bit by default.

However both MAMP and MAMP Pro come in both 32 and 64-bit binaries as of 2.0[1](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-linux.html#oci8).

However, the question is whether your Mac has a 64-bit processor, and whether it runs the 64-bit OS X by default. [This Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3770) offers a guide on how to determine which Mac you have. For example, if you have a Macbook Pro from 2008-2010, it might run the 32-bit kernel by default, but (see the article) you can set it to run the 64-bit kernel instead.

Your quickest path to your goal is probably to build mongo.so for 32-bit though. This article on [using MAMP/PECL to install PHP extensions](http://www.vayanis.com/2010/05/19/os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-using-mamppecl-to-install-php-extensions/) says that with PECL it should be as simple as this:

```
CFLAGS="-arch i386" ./pecl install
```

If that doesn't work, you can try a manual installation, passing 32-bit flags to configure. See [this question for memcached.so installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/169646/memcache-so-wrong-architecture-in-unknown-on-line-0-in-mamp) for methods that will probably work for you.

This should work (based on above and [manual installation instructions for the Mongo driver on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.manual)):

```
tar zxvf mongodb-mongodb-php-driver-<commit_id>.tar.gz
cd mongodb-mongodb-php-driver-<commit_id>
phpize
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5 CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp" CCFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe" CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe" LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bind_at_load" ./configure
sudo make install
```

...then refer to the php.net link above for the rest of the manual installation steps (i.e. adding the extension in your php.ini).

Comment: The bitness of the kernel doesn't affect userland on Mac OS X at all. You can run 64-bit applications on a 32-bit kernel and vice versa.

Comment: @duskwuff What you said is correct. However, _what you can't do_ is use 32-bit MAMP with a 64-bit extension. You can run 32-bit MAMP with a 32-bit `mongo.so`, but using the 64-bit `mongo.so` isn't going to work.